# Why was Captain Ranvijay Singh's dead body released in the sea in the movie "The Ghazi Attack"?

Tags: realism, the-ghazi-attack

In [Ghazi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghazi_(film)) (also called The Ghazi Attack), after Captain Ranvijay Singh died, his body was released in the sea.

**Is it due to religious reasons or is a naval code?**

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antam_Sanskar#Sikh_practices_around_death) mentions

> Cremation is the preferred method of disposal, although if it is not possible any other methods such as burial or **submergence at sea are acceptable.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Burial at sea**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burial_at_sea#Wartime_burial_at_sea) is traditional in many navies *particularly* in wartime.

> Burial at sea is the disposal of human remains in the ocean, normally from a ship or boat. It is regularly performed by navies, and is done by private citizens in many countries.
>
> Burial-at-sea services are conducted at many different locations and with many different customs, either by ship or by aircraft. Usually, either the captain of the ship or aircraft or a religious representative (of the deceased's religion or the state religion) performs the ceremony.
>
> In wartime, attempts are made for burial at sea to follow the same procedure as for peacetime burial at sea, although a ship on a combat mission may not have all the necessary resources available.

Given that cremation is not possible and submergence is acceptable, burial at sea is the most obvious choice.